# Why do I get "uninitialized constant" error in ruby ruport

Tags: ruby, ruport

I am trying to create a report using ruport but I am getting an error.

`in '<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Ruport::Report (NameError) Did you mean? Ruport`

I used the sample code from https://www.rubydoc.info/github/ruport/ruport-util/Ruport/Report

I have the above code in TestExeReport class
In my main class, I have this:
require_relative '../../spec/support/testExeReport'

I have the gems installed.

I tried looking for help with that error message but none solved my problem.

```
require "rubygems"  
require "ruport"  

class TestExeReport < Ruport::Report   

    renders_as_grouping(:style => :inline)    

    def renderable_data(format)  
        table = Table("foo.csv")  
        Grouping(table, :by => "username")  
    end  
end   

report = TestExeReport.new  
report.save_as("bar.pdf")
```

I would like to see a "pdf" report of my "csv" file

Thanks in advance!

Semone.

Comment: I don't know the root cause, but I see the same issue when loading their example. I'll see if I can figure out why & a workaround but wanted you to know it's not just you

Comment: Run that command (ruby -e "require 'ruport'; puts Ruport::VERSION" ) and check if it is installed properly ....

Comment: Yes its installed properly. Here's the output:
```C:\>ruby -e "require 'ruport'; puts Ruport::VERSION"
1.7.1```

Answer (score 1):

The docs you linked appear to be from ruport-utils, which is an addon/extension for ruport.

You can find similar [examples](https://github.com/ruport/ruport-util/tree/master/example) in the repo but the latest commit is 11 years ago that indicate you need another line in your example, after adding `ruport-util` to your Gemfile or installing via `gem install ruport-util`

```
require 'ruport/util'
```

However, you're going to see a dependency error most likely (I did)

Comment: Yes. Its given some other errors. Could you please suggest alternative reporting tools I could possibly try?

Comment: It's hard to suggest one without knowing what the problem area is? PDF generation? CSV to PDF conversion? Theres [smashing](https://github.com/Smashing/smashing) for web/ui dashboards, [prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf) for PDF generation (and a bunch of templates/extensions). You might also look at ruport itself; it's been updated more recently than utils. You should be able to piece together something yourself w/ prawn & the ruby CSV library that mimics whatever that example would output

Comment: Thank you! I am actually looking for reporting tool for my automation tests. Like how many tests passed and failed. If failed then the error message

Comment: If you're using rspec you can specify a different format `--format html --out results.html`. You can also spit it out as JSON (and a couple other formats).